# Blazor: Allow style for custom component

Tags: blazor

The `style` for `InputText` works, but if I add `style` to `MyComponent`, I get "InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'BlazorApp2.Pages.MyComponent' does not have a property matching the name 'style'." How can I enable `style` for `MyComponent`?

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MyComponent style="margin-bottom:10px" />
<InputText @bind-Value="damn" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>
<MyComponent />

@code
{
    string damn;
}
```

MyComponent.razor

```
<div style="background-color:red">
    My component
</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow">
    Lorem ipsum something something
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component renders HTML elements it is not a HTML element. You cannot apply styles like that. You have a few options.

1. Create a parameter that passes the style to the element
   you want to expose.
2. Use attribute splatting to capture the unmatched attributes and apply them
   to an underlying element.

`MyComponent.razor` (Passing style as parameter)

```
<div style="@SomeStyle">
    ...
<div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string SomeStyle { get; set; }
}
```

`MyComponent.razor` (attribute splatting)

```
<div @attributes="InputAttributes">
    ...
<div>
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object>? InputAttributes { get; set; }
}
```